# If array is empty error

Tags: vb.net

The array is a 9 position array declared as a string, I have 9 text boxes that a user can input data into, each writes to one variable in the array.

I am trying to stop filling the array, and move to print it when the user either fills in all 9 text box's, or stops filling them in when he presses the "write to file" button. From my debugging points, it looks like I get down to the "for" loop, but the program crashes with no errors that I can make heads or tails out of (not syntax or variable)... can anyone see what i'm missing?

Thanks

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\foo\test2.txt"

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim aryText(9) As String

    MessageBox.Show(j)
    aryText(0) = "[" & TextBox1.Text & "]"
    j = 0
    MessageBox.Show(j)
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then
        End
    Else
        aryText(1) = "*" & TextBox2.Text & "{label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
        j = j + 1
        MessageBox.Show(j)
    End If

    'If TextBox3.Text IsNot Nothing Then
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox3.Text) Then
        End
    Else
        aryText(2) = TextBox3.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, null" & "}"
        j = j + 1
        MessageBox.Show(j)
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox4.Text) Then
        End
    Else
        aryText(3) = TextBox4.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
        j = j + 1
        MessageBox.Show(j)
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox5.Text) Then
        End
    Else
        aryText(4) = TextBox5.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
        j = j + 1
        MessageBox.Show(j)
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox6.Text) Then
        End
    Else

        aryText(5) = TextBox6.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
        j = j + 1
        MessageBox.Show(j)
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox7.Text) Then
        End
    Else
        aryText(6) = TextBox7.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
        j = j + 1
        MessageBox.Show(j)
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox8.Text) Then
        End
    Else

        aryText(7) = TextBox8.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
        j = j + 1
        MessageBox.Show(j)
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox9.Text) Then
        End
    Else
        aryText(8) = TextBox9.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
        j = j + 1
        MessageBox.Show(j)
    End If


    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)

    MessageBox.Show(j)
    For i = 0 To j

        objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(j))
        i = i + 1
    Next

    objWriter.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Text written to file")





End Sub
```

Comment: add a try/catch...the exception's message will tell you the error, the exception's stacktrack (in debug mode)...will give you the line with the error...in general...I recommend a grid instead of a series of textboxes for whatever you are doing

Comment: It may not be crashing at all - you have lots of `End` statements in there as a response to bad data(?).  `End` is a fairly abrupt/crude way to exist a NET app.

Comment: Why not add a few breakpoints and check what values are contained where.  It will also help you determine the point from where things are not happening as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please don't debug with MessageBoxes. Visual Studio has a lovely debugger.
2. VB.net arrays are declared Dim myArray(UpperBound) As String. So with your 9 text boxes you have an upper bound of 8, indexes 0 to 8
3. You want Exit Sub not End.
4. A For x = 0 to y...Next works by automatically incrementing x (that is what the Next means, Next x) the default is by one but you can change that by adding a Step. If you attempt to change y you will make a mess. Your For...Next will just write the last value in the array 9 times (aryText(j)) because j doesn't change. Don't increment x in the loop; it increments automatically when Next is called.
5. No need to mess with i and j; just use a For Each
6. Using code block for your stream writer ensures all resources are released.

   ```
       Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
           Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\foo\test2.txt"
           Dim aryText(8) As String
           Dim msg As String = "Please fill in all the boxes,"
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(0) = "[" & TextBox1.Text & "]"
           End If
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(1) = "*" & TextBox2.Text & "{label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
           End If
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox3.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(2) = TextBox3.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, null" & "}"
           End If
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox4.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(3) = TextBox4.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
           End If
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox5.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(4) = TextBox5.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
           End If
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox6.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(5) = TextBox6.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
           End If
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox7.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(6) = TextBox7.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
           End If
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox8.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(7) = TextBox8.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
           End If
           If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox9.Text) Then
               MessageBox.Show(msg)
               Exit Sub
           Else
               aryText(8) = TextBox9.Text & " {label: " & "varchar, not null" & "}"
           End If
           Using objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
               For Each s As String In aryText
                   objWriter.WriteLine(s)
               Next
           End Using
           MessageBox.Show("Text written to file")
       End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you!! This really helped!